# How to properly handle backing up a partition?

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, backup

I have a computer running Ubuntu 14.04 partitioned like so:

```
/dev/sda1 --- FAT32 --- 476Mb/4,32Mb used --- boot
unallocated ----------- 1Mb
/dev/sda3 --- ext4 --- 112,27Gb/22,26Gb used --- mount point: /
/dev/sda4 --- ext4 --- 349,30Gb/88,38Gb used --- mount point: /home
/dev/sda2 --- swap --- 3,73Gb/0B used
```

This computer belonged to a former colleague at work. The Ubuntu install is a bit gobbled up and has probably been broken beyond repair. The problem is this machine also probably has data on it that cannot be lost, but ATM, no one is here to figure out what needs to be backed up.

I thought of simply copying the entire partition to a folder(?) on the bigger partition, but IDK if this will miss something important I should backup as well. I would like to be able to "browse" the backup data with the file manager/terminal if need be, but make room for a clean install on the original filesystem partition (if I'm not mistaken, sda3).

If anyone has any insight they can share, I would be very grateful.

**EDIT**

The computer in question is a laptop, and I don't have means of adding other hard drive (no disk bay/external adapter available).
Also, there is no network storage or similar system deployed here ATM.

At most, I could grab a external USB drive and use it to backup everything, but I would prefer not to, as it is mine (not the company's) and I think it isn't in the best condition either.

Comment: There are tons of backup strategies, both graphical and command line, and thus this question seems an opinion poll. Keep in mind, you need to test restoring from backup to know if it works, you can try a VM. See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BackupYourSystem%20 and ask a more specific question about a specific backup tool/strategy.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen I think my question is closed enough to allow for an answer. I'm not inquiring about the best strategy, but for a solution to my specific problem. Even so, I added details that I think will help make the question more oriented. Thank you!

Comment: You can not make a backup unless you 1. Have storage space and 2. know what you want to back up. Your current strategy is flawed and. IMO, in the event of disk failure, a backup on the same disk will fail as well. You need to back up to an alternate location - usb, remote storage space, DVD, etc.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen I agree with your remarks. I feel like I probably won't proceed with this. The backup isn't really a backup in these terms and I'll probably just end up either losing data or breaking anything, neither of which is an option. Should I close the question?

Answer (score 1):

In your place I'd get a new empty drive (with enough space obviously) and `dd` over the whole disk (after creating a checksum for it) so that no data gets lost whatsoever and it remains provable.

Of course the above only works if the drive isn't in use (isn't mounted), so you **will** need another system (which might be a liveUSB) to proceed with this approach.

Otherwise just wait for someone in authority over the data and ask him/her how to proceed.

Comment: Will not work if the disk/partition is in use, I highly advise you run dd from a live usb.

Comment: ^ Well yes, thought that was self-explanatory.

Comment: Unfortunately, that someone, while having _authority_ over the data, can't provide instructions on how to proceed (doesn't know/care?). Also, `dd`'ing to a new drive isn't an option, as we currently can't afford it/don't have it.

Comment: Say what do you have then? Perhaps a central filesystem with enough space?

Comment: @Wolfer not really. I was hoping I could simply create a /backup folder on the /home partition and move everything there; format the `/` partition and use it to install from scratch. Can you elaborate on the hazards/drawbacks of this approach?

Comment: Well you could install a new system on `sda3` and `sda1` and setting `sda4` to be mounted as `/home` just like it is now. The only technical pitfall that you might run into with this approach is when you accidentally format `/home` (check and recheck the file-system settings before hitting accept on the installer). But this causes other sort of problems. Since you modified the disk this way it won't be useful as evidence (not sure if that matters it had come up for me before...).

Comment: Or the previous user had put important stuff on `sda3` and that might be lost. I'd clear at least these pitfalls up with some supervisor and if they find these things an `acceptable risk` then proceed with your idea (this is useful so it won't be you who gets blamed for stuff you have no control over).

Comment: If you do not have the space to back up the entire partition you will either have to back up part of the data (you get to choose what to back up) or purchase storage somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

I would get a new hard disk with a size just over 110Gb (it should cover the current "used). Then add this disk to this system, format it and mount it on a directory aptly named. Like "/backup". Then move your data over to that disk, verify its content, remove this disk. Then reinstall, after you are satisfied with the system mount this backup disk and copy the data over that you need.

Easier but a bit more expensive: get a new hard disk to replace this one (so as big as possible). Remove the current disk, install the new one, install OS and then mount the removed hard disk to a directory so you can copy your stuff over. Easier but more expensive.